# Is this serie divergent? Calculate Max and Min $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ke^k$

Tags: divergent-series

This is the series:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ke^k$$

I need to calculate Max and Min with integral comparison.

$$\int_1^nxe^x dx \leq \sum_{k=1}^n ke^k \leq \int_1^{n+1}xe^xdx$$
Calculate the indefinite integral:

$$ \int xe^xdx = e^x + xe^x = e^x(x-1) + C$$
$$ \big[ e^x(x-1) \big]_1^n \leq \sum_{k=1}^n ke^k \leq \big[ e^x(x-1) \big]_1^{n+1}$$

Calculate the Min:

$$\big[ e^x(x-1) \big]_1^n = e^n(n-1) - e^1(1-1) = e^n(n-1)$$

Calculate the Max:

$$\big[ e^x(x-1) \big]_1^{n+1} = e^{n+1}(n+1-1) - e^1(1-1) = e^{n+1}(n+1-1) = ne^{n+1}$$

So:

$$ e^n(n-1) \leq \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}ke^k \leq ne^{n+1}$$

Now, this is a geometric series with $|e^k|>1$ so it should diverge.

If I calculate the limit:

$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} ke^k = +\infty$$

So the series diverges, correct?

Comment: Do you have to work with integrals or do you just choose to do that? Because it would be much easier to just look at $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty} ke^k$ and conclude from there that the series diverges.

Comment: If $\sum a_n $ converge than $ a_n \to 0$ so yes , you are corret.

Comment: I need to use the integral comparison to find Min and Max

Comment: The series is trivially divergent: the main term is $\geq 2^k$.